# Raylib drawing text in russian

Tags: c, unicode, raylib

I'm trying to display text in Russian using the DrawTextEx function. What I get at the end is not at all what I want. [Display unicode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ul9w.png). I'm using wchar_t, but the compiler gives the following warning: raylib_unicode.c:27: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type.
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

#include "raylib.h"

#define WINDOW_WIDTH    800
#define WINDOW_HEIGHT   600
#define TARGET_FPS      60

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    // setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    InitWindow(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, "unicode");

    wchar_t msg[] = L"Текст, Text.";
    Font font = LoadFontEx("resources/pt-mono_regular.ttf", 48, NULL, 0);

    SetTargetFPS(TARGET_FPS);

    while (!WindowShouldClose()) {
        BeginDrawing();

            ClearBackground(WHITE);

            DrawTextEx(font, msg, (Vector2) {(float) WINDOW_WIDTH / 2,
                        (float) WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2}, 48, 2, BLACK);

        EndDrawing();
    }

    UnloadFont(font);

    CloseWindow();

    return 0;
}
```

Could you please point me to my mistake, everything works fine in the console.

I used wchar_t. I expect correct text output.

Comment: Why do you expect to be able to pass in a `wchar_t*` as the second argument to `DrawTextEx` when it expects a `char*`?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73248161/5382650

Comment: Craig Estey, I'm getting error: 'u8' undeclared. Compiler TCC.

Answer (score 0):

I changed `wchar_t` to `char` and added the following code to the beginning of the program:

```
int codepoints[512] = { 0 };
for (int i = 0; i < 95; i++) codepoints[i] = 32 + I;
for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) codepoints[96 + i] = 0x400 + i;
```

Also changed `NULL` to `codepoints` in `LoadFontEx`.
Works perfectly.

Comment: Why does your changed code work? What is that code supposed to do?

Comment: This fix only works for Cyrillic.  You should try and learn how to deal with the full Unicode spectrum.  raylib supports UTF-8 to represent any codepoint including Cyrillic. Try and investigate how to change your environment to use UTF-8 for the source code encoding.

Comment: chqrlie, In this case, can you provide a link to the simplest source code except text_unicode.c from raylib examples?